# Regex match any single word or nothing

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

There have been several questions on this but none of them have lead me to the answer, they're all too specific or too long and complex. Mine is more general and simple. I have a pattern like this:

```
/you(?:.*)? see/
```

I want it to match all these sentences except the last:

```
you can see
you could see
you see
you could not see
```

At the moment it matches everything but it also matches the last sentence. I need it to only match any one single word or no word. I also tried this pattern but it doesn't quite work either:

```
/you(?:[^\s]+)? see/
```

Answer (score 0):

This one does the job:

```
/^you(?:\s+\w+)?\s+see$/
```

Where `(?:\s+\w+)?` is an optional non capture group that matches 1 or more spaces followed by 1 or more word character (ie. `[a-zA-Z-9_]`)

**In action:**

```
$strings = array(
'you can see',
'you could see',
'you see',
'you could not see',
);

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    if (preg_match('/^you(?:\s+\w+)?\s+see$/', $str)) {
        echo "$str : matches\n";
    } else {
        echo "$str : doesn't match\n";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
you can see : matches
you could see : matches
you see : matches
you could not see : doesn't match
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when I tested it on regex101.com

Comment: @Hasen: Don't trust sites. Make a script to see what it gives. See my edit.

Comment: regex101.com is not some random website, its the standard for checking regex patterns. All patterns work 100%. Your pattern still doesn't work...

Comment: @Hasen: How do you use it? As you can see, I've written a script that works.

Answer (score 0):

I would have deleted the question since I solved it shortly afterwards but there was already a response. I found just changing the pattern to this solved the problem:

```
/you(?:\s[^\s]+)? see/
```

Comment: Be aware that `[^\s]` matches everything that is not a space, for example `&#{[|!%...`